# How to retrieve nested JPA entities in a single query

Tags: java, optimization, jpa, annotations, eclipselink

I am trying to retrieve entities using eclipselink JPA and am looking for a way to reduce the number of queries run to retrieve a single entity. I believe I should be using the @JoinFetch annotation to retrieve sub-entities in the same query as the main entity. This works fine for a single level of join, but not for multiple levels.

In the example below, EntityA contains a collection of EntityB which contains an EntityC. When I retrieve EntityA, I want a single query to return all 3 sets of entity data. In reality it generates 2 queries, 1 joining EntityA and EntityB and then a separate query joining EntityB and EntityC.

Is it possible to combine this into one query?

```
class EntityA {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityALink", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinFetch
    private Collection<EntityB> entityBs;
}

class EntityB {
    @JoinColumn(name = "X", referencedColumnName = "Y")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private EntityA entityALink;

    @JoinColumn(name = "A", referencedColumnName = "B")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinFetch
    private EntityC entityCLink;
}

class EntityC {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SomeColumn")
    private String someField
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need reduce number of queries, you may using lazy initialization - FetchType.LAZY instead of FetchType.EAGER - in this way jpa get data from databases when need. But you must remember, this is not working when entity is disconnected from manager. So if you send this entity to other servers in serialize the form (ex. in multi-level application) you must again connected this entity with manager. If you application runs in one server, then you don't have this problem.

Summing up is not the exact answer to your question, but maybe helpful for optimize this code.

Exact answer for you question:
You may using named queries, but then query is parse to sql native query, and you don't sure that this working as you want. But maybe you may using native query method?

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ... your queries")
```

For this purpose, please read about using @SqlResultSetMapping annotation to configure result entity class...

Comment: My main goal here is to load up a very large dataset at application startup in as quick a time as possible and not need to return to the database again afterwards. So lazy fetching is just putting off the problem until the data is required. The approach so far is to use entity annotations to specify joins but I do wonder now if named queries would provide a better solution.

Comment: If you do not want to use native query, maybe better using database views, and create other entity with A and B fields? But this is not resolve problem with many to one multiplicity. However, it may can be simplified to a single view in your case?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end I solved this problem using queries and lazy fetching. Instead of expecting JPA to return all the data I wanted in one go (which was far too slow), I opted for my DAO to call 2 separate queries and stitch the data together itself. The links between entities are now lazy instead of eager and it is up to the queries to determine how much data is brought back. I'm using eclipselink and so was able to specify query hints to optimise the joins between tables.

Answer (score 0):

First write a query to get EntityA.

```
EntityA entity = <your Query> ;
```

then call

```
Collection<EntityB> entityB = entity.getEntityBs();
for(EntityB eachB : entityB){

    EntityC entityCLink = eachB.getEntityCLink();
}
```

**Note**: Create setter & getters in each entity.